# Setting Pin Assignments For Quartus

Tags: fpga, pins, intel-fpga, quartus

So I have written a simple Verilog module which works well in the ModelSim emulator. I would like to now program my Cyclone 10 Dev board to perform this simple task, but I need to set up the pin assignments on my qsf file.

That being said, I don't know where to find the correct pins and how I would assign them to the inputs and outputs of my module. The model I am using is a 10CL025YU256I7G

Comment: Your "cyclone 10 Dev board" probably comes with an example project from which you can take a pin mapping file, or with the documentation to build one, or maybe it's even predefined in Altera's tool to generate pin mapping definitions. Since we don't know which board you're referring to, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the Intel® Cyclone® 10 LP FPGA Evaluation Kit.

Here's the user guide: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug-c10-lp-eval-kit.pdf

In that document it lists the the user i/o LEDs, push-buttons, switches, and others which you may want to use:

[image]
[image]

From the schematic you can see the names of the pins those are attached to those i/o in black.

[image]

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/support/boards-kits/cyclone10/c10lp-eval-a1-sch.PDF

You can then assign them to your module's nets with settings such the following in your QSF:

```
set_location_assignment PIN_M16 -to your_hdl_signal
```

Links from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/products/boards_and_kits/dev-kits/altera/cyclone-10-lp-evaluation-kit.html)

Comment: I believe R138 is just the resistor in the schematics, not the pin? The PDF you linked suggests USER_LED0..3 connected to L14, K15, J14, J13.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Updated.